# using stringstream and getline to read the first two numbers of each line

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream, istringstream

What I need to do: I have a vector of lines right now, `v[0]` is the first line and so on. I would like to read the first number from each line as the challenge and the second number from each line as the judge and then apply the conditions in the code. I want to use a `stringstream` to read extract the numbers from the lines.

What my code is doing right now: It is reading only the first number from each line. So the first number of the first line is the challenge and the first number of the second line is the judge and the first number of the third line is the challenge.

```
    std::vector<string> v;
    string line;
    int i;
    double challenge;
    int judge;

    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        if (line.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        v.push_back(line);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < v.size();i++ ) {
        cin >> v[i];
        std::stringstream ss(v[i]);
        ss << v[i];
        ss >> challenge >> judge;

        if (challenge < 1 || challenge > 5) {
            cout << "bad_difficulty" << endl; //must add the condition or empty
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        }

        if (judge != 5 || judge != 7 ) {
            cout << "bad_judges" << endl; //must add the condition or empty
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        }

        cout << v[i] << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example:

```
Input:
 5.1 7 5.4 3.0 9.6 2.9 2.8 2.0 5.4
-3.8 7 2.9 1.1 5.7 7.2 4.8 8.5 3.9
 2.2 5 9.4 4.7 7.3 1.9 5.7 6.0 7.1
 2.4 6 9.2 5.2 1.0 2.9 4.9 7.4 7.9
 2.1 7 7.9 4.9 0.0 7.2 9.1 7.8 6.7 4.3
 3.8 5
 2.0
 4.0 7 2.4 1.9 3.2 8.3 14.8 0.1 9.7
 2.5 7 8.4 -8.0 5.0 6.0 8.0 1.3 3.3
 1.6 -1 9.5 2.5 5.8 7.9 5.5 1.6 7.9

Output should be:
bad_difficulty
bad_difficulty
2.2 5 9.4 4.7 7.3 1.9 5.7 6.0 7.1
bad_judges
2.1 7 7.9 4.9 0.0 7.2 9.1 7.8 6.7 4.3
3.8 5
bad_judges
4.0 7 2.4 1.9 3.2 8.3 14.8 0.1 9.7
2.5 7 8.4 -8.0 5.0 6.0 8.0 1.3 3.3
bad_judges

Current Output:
bad_difficulty
bad_judges
2.2 5 9.4 4.7 7.3 1.9 5.7 6.0 7.1
bad_judges
2.1 7 7.9 4.9 0.0 7.2 9.1 7.8 6.7 4.3
bad_judges
2.0
bad_judges
2.5 7 8.4 -8.0 5.0 6.0 8.0 1.3 3.3
bad_judges
1.6 -1 9.5 2.5 5.8 7.9 5.5 1.6 7.9
```

Comment: What's the question? `judge != 5 || judge != 7` doesn't look good to me.

Comment: I posted an example. The judge number which is the second number of the line should either be 5 or 7 otherwise it is a bad_judges

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: Hi Jonny, I edited the post

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `judge`?

Comment: I forgot to copy this part. I did edit it now, sorry. I use ss >> challenge >> judge or even when I separate them ss>> challenge then the if statement then ss>> judge then the if statement it is the same result and the same output as the one above

Comment: Why are you initializing the `stringstream` with `v[i]` and then reading `v[i]` into the `stringstream`? Also why is `i++` not in the for statement?

Comment: One thing to watch out for is what happens after you remove an entry from the vector. Consider `v[i]` where i = 1. Bad entry, so you remove it. That moves all elements up one. `v[2]` is now `v[1]`. Unfortunately `i` is always incremented so the new `v[1]` is never tested.

Comment: @jonny, I dont know how to use stringstream quite well. How do I fix that?

Comment: @user3328381 you don't fix what Henly is worried about. Other than not testing to make sure both `challenge` and `judge` were read successfully, you got the read right. To make sure you read, `if (ss >> challenge >> judge) { /* use challenge and judge */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go walking through that delete loop.

```
i = 0
v[0] contains line 1. 
Line 1 is 5.1 7
challenge > 5, remove 0. The vector shifts up by 1 v[0] now contains line 2
Judge == 7 do not remove 0
increment i

i = 1
v[1] contains line 3. Line 2 has been skipped
Line 3 is 2.2 5
challenge < 5, do not remove 1. 
Judge is not 5 or 7. remove 1. The vector shifts up by 1 v[1] now contains line 4
increment i

i = 2
v[2] contains line 5. Line 4 has been skipped
Line 5 is 2.1 7
challenge < 5, do not remove 2. 
Judge is 7. do not remove 2. 
increment i

i = 3
v[3] contains line 6. 
Line 6 is 3.8 5
challenge < 5, do not remove 3. 
Judge is 5. do not remove 3. 
increment i

i = 3
v[3] contains line 7. 
Line 7 is  2.0
challenge < 5, do not remove 3. 
Judge is UNDEFINED! PANIC! PANIC! Crom only knows what happens.
increment i
```

Anyway, the basic pattern here should be clear. When you remove an element from a `vector`, all subsequent elements are shifted up. Solution: When you remove an element, do not increment `i`. An `else`statement will take care of this for you.

Next because there are two separate `if` statements there is the possibility that both conditions will be true and `v[i]` will be removed twice. There are a bunch of ways around this. Manthan Tilva's solution with `continue` is simple and effective, but this can be handled more obviously with an `else if` or by rolling both tests into the same `if`.

Third, using values that were not read from the stream are undefined. and should not be used. Discard the line without looking any further. `if (ss >> challenge >> judge)` will help here.

Comment: Your code works Manthan! There is another step to go further. I need to read all the numbers after the judge in a vector (to compare those numbers and get the highest one and to see if after each 5 judges we have exactly five numbers and after each 7 judge we have exactly 7 judges in the line). Is it possible to do ss >> vector[i] in a for loop (i=0; i < vector.size(); i++) . How can I possibly do it?